# how to connect kognitio database from mysql

Tags: mysql, database, connection, kognitio-wx2, kognitio

I need to select some data from WX2 Database and put it in MYSQL DB.
Can any one help me on this?
Is ODBC.ini configuration will work for the mysql database to connect to WX2 database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To access the data in Kognitio you could use the ODBC driver to retrieve it, or for better performance use the bulk unloader utilities to export it as CSV, which you could then load into MySQL.

If you were going the other way round, pulling data FROM MySQL TO Kognitio, you could bulk unload as CSV from MySQL then bulk load into Kognitio, or you could use the External Table functionality of version 8 to access MySQL tables on demand from Kognitio via an ODBC connector.

The documentation covers off all these approaches.